Hebrew is aligned incorrectly (LTR) via Telegram bot API
When using Telegram bot API the text in Hebrew should be aligned RTL. Instead it is aligned incorrectly in LTR.
Request:
POST /botXXXXXXXXXXX:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/sendPhoto HTTP/1.1
Host: api.telegram.org
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 134

{
    "chat_id": "XXXXXXXXX",
    "photo": "XXXXXXXXX",
    "caption": "בדיקה",
    "parse_mode": "HTML"
}

Result (the red arrow shows how the text should have been aligned):

Please help how can this be fixed. Thanks

Please share an [mre] as that text send with sendPhoto is just right to left

@0stone0 not sure what does not meet the requirements in the link provided. Is it better now? Thanks

No I mean that send a photo with that caption results in RTL text, so we're not able to help you since we cant reproduce the issue. probably due to your device settings.

what makes you think hebrew characters make it display in RTL?

This should be supported according to here.

@0stone0 the image in the screenshot is pitch black. Not blocked by the device.

I don't think you understood my previous message. The text is RTL as shown on the picture. The fact that you're sering it as LTR is probably a client sided thingy.

I don't think it's client related. I even set my ui language to Hebrew and still the same.

If you send yourself the message, is the text RTL or LTR?

LTR as well when sending myself via the app GUI. But if the caption contains a new line then it displays it correctly in RTL. This seems like a bug/random behavior from the app side.

This is a client issue not a server issue.
Sending one message with the code you provide, result in:
on desktop

properly aligned (auto detection)
on mobile 
Not properly aligned (language detection failed)

I already stated that in a comment, don't see this as a valid answer.

@0stone0, you have not stated that it works on some device and not on others. Plus, stating there is no answer is in itself a valid answer.
